# Dealing with class imbalance in unsupervised learning

Tags: python, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I'm using K-mean clustering and I have no idea about the true labels of the data. I used PCA and I've got 4 clusters. However, the clusters seem to be imbalanced.
I was wondering how I can fix the class imbalanced problem in this unsupervised learning task?

Comment: What makes you think the clusters should be balanced?

Comment: I think I have the mindset of supervised learning, in which class imbalanced is a must. I actually don't know if this should be the case in unsupervised learning... Can you make it a bit more clear for me ?

Comment: If you plan on using these clusters as a feature in another model the class imbalance could be an issue, but for the sake of separating into the most distinct n groups kmeans doesn't care about balancing. If you had a house that cost $1m dollars and 500 that cost $100k the single expensive house should be in it's own cluster.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that makes sense. I actually like to use the clusters and feed it into a predictive model later on. Do you have any suggestions on how i should deal with the class imbalance in this scenario?